# Usage of this pointer in c++

Tags: c++, this

I confused what does it mean `this` pointer and how it is used exactly. in the below examples give the same output. What is the difference putting reference operator(&) in the `setX` and `setY` functions?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj1;
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

With reference operator

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test &setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj1;
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you return `Test` by value, you return a *copy* of your object. If you return `Test` by reference, you receive a reference to exact object you're currently working on (i.e. `*this`).

Comment: There is no such thing as "reference operator", in this case `&` is a part of type `Test &` so function returns a reference to current object instead of copied temporary object.

Comment: One question per question please

Answer (score 3):

When you return by value, as in

```
Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
```

then you return a ***copy*** of the object. And the copy is totally unrelated to the original object.

When you return a reference, you return a reference to the actual object, no copies are made.

And because of this difference the two programs you show should *not* produce the same output. The first should say that `x` is equal to `10` (because you set `x` on the `obj1` object) but then you set `y` on the copy returned by `setX`, meaning that `obj1.y` will still be zero. [See e.g. this example](https://ideone.com/J0oCJ0).